# How to apply different Themes to parts of a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, routes, themes

My app has different parts and I want them to have different theme colors, including for all the subroutes in the navigation.

But if I use a Theme, it's not applied to the widgets in the subroutes.
I also tried to use nested MaterialApps but this won't work because I can't pop back to the root menu.
I'd prefer not to have to pass a Color parameter to all the screens.
What should I do?

Here is a test code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: _Test()));
}

class _Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Red section'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red)),
                      child: _TestSubRoute(),
                    );
                  },
                ));
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Green section'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.green)),
                      child: _TestSubRoute(),
                    );
                  },
                ));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TestSubRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.2),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Should keep the same color through the navigation...'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Hello'),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text('OK'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Push...'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _TestSubRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I finally found.
Each section is in a MaterialApp with its own ThemeData.
To get back to the root screen, I use a BackButton with

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop()`

Contrary to other solutions, this does not force to change all sub-screens,
but only the first screen of each section.

Comment: This answer isn't that clear, feels like a comment on some other answers

Answer (score 5):

you can set a custom different `ThemeData` to a part of the widget tree using the `Theme` widget like this:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.purple,
  ),
  child: YourWidget(),
);
```

in Flutter the `Theme` is an `InheritedWidget` so that the `ThemeData` you set to the `data` property will be applied to the whole subtree of the child property, even if you separate your widget into multiples widgets..., they will refer to the closet `Theme` widget in the widget tree using the `context`.

the `MaterialApp` has the default one nested inside of it, so when we do the:

```
Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
```

it gets us the `primaryColor` from the `MaterialApp`'s nested `Theme` since it's the closet.

but when you specify a Theme widget to a part of your widget tree like the example above, anything inside the `YourWidget()` will refer to that `ThemeData`

see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html

Comment: That's what I've done in my code above but it does not work, the theme is not applied in the subroutes.

Comment: show me a snippet of what you did

Comment: Please try the demo code in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I use another approach for this solution, `InheritedWidget`.

Basically:

- Define your `InheritedWidget` where you will call the updated theme.
- Create a `StatefulWidget` wrapper class that contains the `InheritedWidget` and the `MaterialApp`(where you going to update the Theme).
- Keep your first screen with its own theme : `data: ThemeData.light(),`.
- The only thing you need to do is to call `ThemeProvider.of(context).updateTheme(yournewtheme)` before pushing the new screen.

Result:

[image]

This is the code I used, based on your example:

```dart
main() {
  runApp(
    ThemeWrapper(
      child: _Test(),
    ),
  );
}

class ThemeProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final ValueChanged<ThemeData> onThemeUpdated;

  const ThemeProvider({
    required this.onThemeUpdated,
    required super.child,
    super.key,
  });

  static ThemeProvider of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<ThemeProvider>()!;

  void updateTheme(ThemeData data) {
    onThemeUpdated(data);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant ThemeProvider oldWidget) => false;
}

class ThemeWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const ThemeWrapper({required this.child, super.key});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ThemeWrapper> createState() => _ThemeWrapperState();
}

class _ThemeWrapperState extends State<ThemeWrapper> {
  ThemeData? _theme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeProvider(
      onThemeUpdated: (newTheme) {
        setState(() {
          _theme = newTheme;
        });
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: _theme,
        home: _Test(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData.light(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Red section'),
                onPressed: () {
                  ThemeProvider.of(context).updateTheme(
                    ThemeData(
                      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  );
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return _TestSubRoute();
                    },
                  ));
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Green section'),
                onPressed: () {
                  ThemeProvider.of(context).updateTheme(
                    ThemeData(
                      colorScheme:
                          const ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  );
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return _TestSubRoute();
                    },
                  ));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TestSubRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.2),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:
            const Text('Should keep the same color through the navigation...'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('Hello'),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: const Text('OK'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Push...'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _TestSubRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code - You are calling Navigator.push() on _TestSubRoute() from _Test and supplying ThemeData.

You are then calling Navigator.push()on _TestSubRoute() from within _TestSubRoute() itself but not supplying ThemeData.

If you really just want to add a global theme you can do it in your main like this:

```
main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: _Test(), theme: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red)),));
}
```

Otherwise, I've noticed that both your widgets are Stateless which means that they will not change or hold state based on Theme.data which is only scoped within Navigator.push()in _Test()

If you want to dynamically change themes for _TestSubRoute(), you will need to use stateful widgets and store ThemeData in the parent widget and change that based on your requirement e.g., onPressed(), onTap() etc.

If you want to still want use just stateless widgets for trivial apps, you will need to specify the ThemeData each time you use Navigator.push() as flutter is not going to set any state for those widgets.

If you want to add a global theme as mentioned by other answers, in your code you can do it like this:

Here is some info from the flutter website:

> A widget is either stateful or stateless. If a widget can change—when a user interacts with it, for example—it’s stateful.

> A stateless widget never changes. Icon, IconButton, and Text are examples of stateless widgets. Stateless widgets subclass StatelessWidget.

> A stateful widget is dynamic: for example, it can change its appearance in response to events triggered by user interactions or when it receives data. Checkbox, Radio, Slider, InkWell, Form, and TextField are examples of stateful widgets. Stateful widgets subclass StatefulWidget.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want a single global theme for all my app, but different sub-themes for different sections of my app (let's call them sub-apps) including all the sub-routes. If possible I'd like to avoid adding a color state to each of the screen widgets (there are many). The ideal solution would be something like nested MaterialApps, but I don't know how to pop back from a sub-app to the root app.

Comment: Are you able to define ThemeData for your sub routes in a separate file and then pass the relevant Themedata when pushing a material page. All widgets within that sub route should inherit the Themedata you supplied. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you wrap the Scaffold widget for the sub route with the ThemeData, the widget tree will inherit the Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a nice workaround below. The idea is - you get the theme of the route and then apply it to the subroutes.

````
main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: _Test()));
}

class _Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Red section'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red)),
                      child: _TestSubRoute(),
                    );
                  },
                ));
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Green section'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.green)),
                      child: _TestSubRoute(),
                    );
                  },
                ));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _TestSubRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.2),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Should keep the same color through the navigation...'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Hello'),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text('OK'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Push...'),
          onPressed: () {
            final theme = Theme.of(context);

            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Theme(
                data: theme,
                child: _TestSubRoute()
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Nice but this forces me to change all Navigator.push calls. Please see the other solution that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple MaterialApp, you can wrap your scaffold in Navigator and Theme widget. This way, same theme will be applied to all the sub-routes.

Now, if you want to pop to root navigator, you may choose to do
`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();`

This will pop the entire nested Navigators.